# fs invocation vs side effect ordering?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is the order in which asynchonours filesystem operations invoked guaranteed to be the same order they are actually performed on the file system.

e.g.

```
// foo.tmp exists
fs.exists('foo.tmp', (err, value) => console.log(value))
fs.unlink('foo.tmp')
```

Is `true` guaranteed to be the output?

Comment: You'd expect fs operations to be executed in parallel, not to be queued; so I can't imagine there's a guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) tells that there's no guarantee:

> With the asynchronous methods there is no guaranteed ordering. So the
>   following is prone to error:
>
> ```
> fs.rename('/tmp/hello', '/tmp/world', (err) => {
>   if (err) throw err;
>   console.log('renamed complete');
> });
> fs.stat('/tmp/world', (err, stats) => {
>   if (err) throw err;
>   console.log(`stats: ${JSON.stringify(stats)}`);
> });
> ```
>
> It could be that fs.stat is executed before fs.rename. The correct way
>   to do this is to chain the callbacks.